# Algorithm to look for next value changes

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a Name and Int stored in table, where in Int column has 0 or 1 as its value.

```
    N1, 1
    N2, 0,
    N3, 0
    N4, 0,
    N5, 1
    N6, 0,
    N7, 0,
    N8, 1
    N9 0
    N10 0
    N11 1
```

I need to look for next Value changes from 0 to 1.
I need the key value pair output as (N2, N5) WHERE in N2 it had 0, then 1 was at N5. Same way (N2, N5), (N6, N8) and (N9, N11)

Any idea how can i write algorithm efficiently for more than 100k records?

Comment: In the above example, it looks for first occurrence of 0, then it look for the occurrence of 1 and make a pair. and so on

Comment: Your question is too broad, but can't you just loop and read every line (memoizing state from previous ones). BTW, you should consider [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) to store that data.

Comment: No other algorithms can be used other than foreach loop? Since this has more than 100k records, performance is the main thing i need to consider.

Comment: If you need to do this just once, there is no algorithm which would help in efficiency, you have to go through all the data anyway, and getting desired output along the way is basically free already.

Comment: 100K records is not much. Probably can be processed in a small fraction of second (perhaps a few dozen milliseconds) on a current laptop or desktop.

Comment: Ok. If this about using SQL on some database, add relevant tags. Also we should see your too slow code. And know what these performance requirements actually are. Because looping 100k iterations should really be very fast even on Perl.

Comment: Like, if you do 100k DB queries, then your problem is right there... C will not help one bit. Butbwe don't know, because you don't show your problem code.

Comment: There are sporadic commas in the input shown.  Is the real data as bad?  Is the name always a single word (no spaces) or can there be multiple words?  How did you manage to botch the Perl so it was too slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the data, keeping track of the first occurence of a 0 and 1, to make a pair.

If you need to do that only once, then this is the way to go. Moreover 100k+ records is not that big and C can tackle that happily.

You *could* gain some speedup by short-circuiting your if statements (for example if you already found a zero, don't search for another one, until 1 has been found, thus a pair has been made).

Like this, in pseudocode:

```
string first_0 = "";
for row in table:
  if first_0 == "" && row.Int == 0:
    first_0 = row.Name;
  if first_0 != "" && row.Int == 1:
    print pair(first_0, row.Name);
    first_0 = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provide enough details of your problem data structures, but general solution for case of many queries might look simple:

Add additional field (or linked table) `nextChange`.
Traverse your table in reverse direction, keeping `lastOne` and `lastZero` id's (or name)

```
 int lastValues[2];
 for i = last to first
      currentEntry.nextChange = lastValues[1 - currentEntry.Value];
      lastValues[currentEntry.Value] = currentEntry.id
```